# UITableViewCell fit textLabel to entire frame

Tags: uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to get my `UITableViewCell.textLabel` property to autofit text both vertically and horizontally.

Right now my `tableView` is not scrollable, so the `cell` frame is not dynamic. I need the `textLabel` property to word wrap and resize to a set # of lines. Setting the `numberOfLines` to 0  isn't working because it cut off because my `cell` height is smaller than the `textLabel` final height. Using an arbitrary number for `numberOfLines` cuts off the text.

How can I resize my `textLabel` to fit within the `frame` of the `cell`?

Code below

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView @"mycell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"LOTS OF TEXT";

    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [cell.textLabel textRectForBounds:cell.bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:0];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.textLabel.minimumScaleFactor = .5;
}
```

Comment: you mean you want to resize the cell based on textLable content?

Comment: @sanginadhammurali no, the cell is static in height. I want to resize the `textLabel` based on the static height

Comment: try to give textlable frame x and y positions to (0,0) in nib file and if if the text lines more than two and even after NSLineBreakByWordWrapping is given,is not working then increase the textlable hieght it will work.

Comment: @sanginadhammurali that completely misses the point of the question

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If the cells are a set height this is straightforward. You will have to set a custom cell and textLabel in it, as I don't think you can't modify the textLabel in the basic or other preset cells the way you need to. Just add a text label and set constraints linking it to the four sides, with the minimum amount (can be zero). Labels automatically center text vertically if there is extra space, so making the label too tall shouldn't be a problem.

Original answer:

---

If you're not using tableView self-sizing cells, maybe to support iOS 7, then it won't matter what you do in the cell because the issue is in the tableView row heights. If a single label the classic boundingRect method will work. in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexpath:` do

```
    NSString *stringFromDataSource = @"Text For Label";
    CGSize potentialSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.tableview.frame), CGFLOAT_MAX);
    NSStringDrawingOptions optionsForMultiline = NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading;
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                             NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]
                             }; //or whatever
    CGRect rectForText = [stringFromDataSource boundingRectWithSize:potentialSize
                                     options:optionsForMultiline
                                  attributes:attributes
                                     context:nil];
    return CGRectGetHeight(rectForText);
```

Note that in your question, your various options for sizing the cell aren't going to be used if the textLabel is expanding with autolayout, unless there is a constraint capping the maximum size, at which point `minimumScaleFactor` and so on will kick in.

Comment: I want my `cell` to be static height so wouldn't the above not work  ?

Comment: this still doesn't work. Creating a custom prototype cell with a UILabel with autolayout contained to margins still cuts off the label text